# Spring Controller not invoking SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to setup basic Spring MVC project, but I am facing this issue. Constructor of MainController is also not invoking.

[This is the servlet configuration file (xml).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSrKR.png)

[This is web.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70K8L.png)

[This is MainController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpvdw.png)

[This is hello.jsp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o7rb.png)

[This is displayname.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3WjM.png)

[This is the error I am getting whenever I am running the code on tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgZSs.png)

I am not able to access any of the URL
http://localhost:8080/WebProject/view/
http://localhost:8080/WebProject/
http://localhost:8080/WebProject/view/hello

This URL is able to run the hellp.jsp file
http://localhost:8080/WebProject/view/hello.jsp
But whenever I am trying to submit the form which is there in hello.jsp, I am getting 404 error. Refer image 7 for that.
[Refer Image 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGXcs.png)

I am bale to access page displayname using this URL
http://localhost:8080/WebProject/view/displayname.jsp?firstname=xx
but the name is not showing. It is null in this case. Refer image 8.
[Refer Image 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwiF4.png)

Tomcat version I am using is 10.
Spring version above 5.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid giving external image url for code and errors. you can edit you question and write code snippet which is not working and share the error in body section of the question.

Comment: Images are pasted and uploaded to stack overflows server sir @AtulDwivedi . I pasted image link so that question length would be small. Please help if possible.

Comment: You are far more likely to get help if you follow the recommendations.

Comment: If starting to learn java and spring boot, try to avoid xmls as much as you can. Go for NO-XMLs and annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Tomcat 10 is not working with Spring 5 due to package renaming, downgrade to Tomcat 9.
2. Also in your XML view resolver it should be

   /WEB-INF/view/

not

```
/view/
```

3. And your view folder MUST BE LOCATED INSIDE WEB-INF folder
4. And in your controller delete line 10,12,13,14. That is the reason why you are getting 404, because you did not handle root URL ( "/" ) in your controller.
5. Also I would suggest downgrading to JDK8, it is the easiest and one of the best JDKs for learning Java.

Comment: Downgrading from tomcat 10 to Tomcat 9 works. Thank you so much. I was struggling since the last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Spring's `Model` class to set values for your view. You can make below changes to you code to utilise it.

`MainController.java`

```
    @RequestMapping("/displayname")
    public String displayname(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
        model.addAttribute("firstName", firstName);
        return "displayname";
    }
```

And change line number `11` of `displayname.jsp` like below:

```
 Hello ${firstName}
```